# AlarmManager time seems sporadic

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to get a service to run every 15 minutes using the AlarmManager, if the stop button is pressed I am trying to cancel the Alarm and reset it for 60 minutes.

It does not seem to be waiting either 15 mins or 60 mins if the button is pressed. Last time I pressed the stop button it was about a 1 min wait before the the service was ran again.

I'm new to AlarmManager and android dev in general, can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Main class

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity {
private Thread thread;
private String CurrentString;
private int MaxCalls;
private int cph;
private int mht;
private String alarm;
private int timer =10000;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private TextView MaxCallstxt,MHTtxt,CPHtxt;
private static final String TAG = "MainScreen";
private Date inTime,outTime,inputTime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

    registerReceiver(uiUpdated, new IntentFilter("LOCATION_UPDATED"));
    final Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    final PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);


    final AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            15*60*1000, pintent);


    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainScreen.this, R.raw.rescueme);
    Button SoundButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
    SoundButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onTouchListener");

            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                //stop or pause your media player mediaPlayer.stop(); or mediaPlayer.pause();
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);

                stopService(myIntent);
                alarm.cancel(pintent);
                alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                        60*60*1000, pintent);

             }
            return false;
        }
    });


    MaxCallstxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Maxcallstxt);
    CPHtxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CPHtxt);
    MHTtxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MHTtxt);

};

private BroadcastReceiver uiUpdated= new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Date mToday = new Date();
        String ts = tsLong.toString();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
        String curTime = sdf.format(mToday);
        try {

             inputTime = sdf.parse(curTime);
             inTime = sdf.parse("07:00");
             outTime = sdf.parse("23:59");

        }
        catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in formatting " + e.toString());
    }

        String[] separated = intent.getExtras().getString("MaxCalls").split("\\|");
        MaxCalls = Integer.parseInt(separated[0].toString()); // MaxCalls
        cph = Integer.parseInt(separated[1].toString()); // cph
        mht = Integer.parseInt(separated[2].toString()); // mht
        alarm = separated[3].toString(); // Alarm = true/False

        MaxCallstxt.setText("Max Calls : " + MaxCalls);
        MHTtxt.setText("MHT : " + mht);
        CPHtxt.setText("CPH : " + cph);

        alarm = "True";

        if (alarm.equals("True"))
        {
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
            }
            else
            {
                if((inputTime.after(inTime) && inputTime.before(outTime)) || (MaxCalls == 0 && cph== 0 && mht ==0))
                {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }

            }

        }


    }
};

public static String GET(String url){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // make GET request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

        // receive response  as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // convert inputstream to string
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    return result;
}

// convert inputstream to String
private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

MyService class

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";
MediaPlayer player;
private Thread thread;
private String CurrentString;
private int timer =10000;
private boolean firsttime = true;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

   player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rescueme);
   player.setLooping(false); // Set looping


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    player.stop();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         //   while(true)
        //    {
                try {

                    Global g = new Global();
                    timer=g.get_timer();
                    firsttime=g.get_firsttime();
                   if (firsttime == true)
                    {
                        g.set_firstime(false);
                    }else{
                        Thread.sleep(0);
                   }



                    CurrentString =GET("http://example.com/example.aspx");
                    Intent i = new Intent("LOCATION_UPDATED");
                    i.putExtra("MaxCalls",CurrentString);
                    sendBroadcast(i);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //REST OF CODE HERE//
            }

     //   }
    }).start();

    //  player.start();
}

public static String GET(String url){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // make GET request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

        // receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // convert inputstream to string
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";


    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    return result;
}

// convert inputstream to String
private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}
```

}

Logcat of the service starting and stopping

```
11-07 16:21:45.469    1268-1268/com.jtechltd.networktraffic D/MyService﹕ onCreate
11-07 16:21:45.529    1268-1268/com.jtechltd.networktraffic D/MyService﹕ onStart
11-07 16:21:49.709    1268-1268/com.jtechltd.networktraffic D/MainScreen﹕ onTouchListener
11-07 16:21:49.799    1268-1268/com.jtechltd.networktraffic D/MainScreen﹕ onTouchListener
11-07 16:21:50.009    1268-1268/com.jtechltd.networktraffic D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 219K,  7% free 4418K/4704K, paused 50ms, total 62ms
11-07 16:21:50.089    1268-1268/com.jtechltd.networktraffic D/MyService﹕ onDestroy
11-07 16:22:45.499    1268-1268/com.jtechltd.networktraffic D/MyService﹕ onCreate
11-07 16:22:45.559    1268-1268/com.jtechltd.networktraffic D/MyService﹕ onStart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd parameter (triggerAtMillis) of setInexactRepeating/setRepeating method is the time that the alarm should first trigger. The alarm will not fire before this time. When you set it to cal.getTimeInMillis() you are setting it to trigger at the same moment.

Set it to **(cal.getTimeInMillis() + 15*60*1000)** and **(cal.getTimeInMillis() + 60*60*1000)** instead of cal.getTimeInMillis() and try again.

**triggerAtMillis = cal.getTimeInMillis() + intervalMillis**

And also use setInexactRepeating instead of setRepeating. Read docs for more info on this.